# Module jquery resolves to a non-module entity

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-framework

When trying to load jQuery into a SharePoint Framework project I am running into this error:

`Module ''jquery'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct`

I followed the [spfx docs](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library) to set it up.

Here are the steps I take after creating a brand new project using the yo generator:

1. `npm install --save @types/jquery`
2. Add `"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"` to the config file so it now looks like this

   `{
     "entries": [
       {
         "entry": "./lib/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.js",
         "manifest": "./src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json",
         "outputPath": "./dist/hello-world.bundle.js"
       }
     ],
     "externals": {
       "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
     },
     "localizedResources": {
       "helloWorldStrings": "webparts/helloWorld/loc/{locale}.js"
     }
   }`
3. When I add `import * as $ from 'jquery';` I get the error above. `gulp serve` fails as well.

[image: jQuery Error]

Comment: try using the below syntax. import jQuery = require('jquery')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with [@types/jquery version 3.2 and 3.2.1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17239)

If you change the version of @types/jquery to 2.0.47 everything works as expected.

Steps I took:

1. `npm uninstall @types/jquery`
2. Update `package.json` dependency: `"@types/jquery": "2.0.47"`
3. `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as below :

```
"externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    }    
},
```

> In order to define an external script as a non-AMD script you need to
>   specify the name of the global variable to which the script will be
>   attached using the globalName property

Reference - [Building SharePoint Framework Client Side Web Parts using jQuery](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-jquery-plugins-cdn/)

Also, ensure that the jquery entry is present  in the `tsconfig.json` file(found in the root of the solution folder) as below, if not add it:

```
"types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jquery"
    ]
```

So, your full entry would be somewhat as:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "es6-collections",
      "webpack-env",
      "jquery"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that as well and still get the same error.

Comment: ensure the `jquery` is present in the `tsconfig` file. Have updated answer accordingly. So, add the entry in the `tsconfig` ,then stop gulp and then do a `gulp serve` again, should work now

Comment: You are right in that `jquery` wasn't in the tsconfig.json file.  I added it and re-tried `gulp serve` but I am still getting the same error.